# How to Update and sync a Database tables at exactly same time?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, triggers

**I need to sync**(upload first to remote DB-download to mobile device next) **DB tables with remote DB from mobile device** (which may insert/update/delete rows from multiple tables).

The remote DB performs other operation based on uploaded sync data.When sync continues to download data to mobile device the remote DB still performing the previous tasks and leads to sync fail. something like **'critical condition'** where both **'sync and DB-operations'** want access remote Databse. How to solve this issue? is it possible to do sync DB and operate on same DB at a time?

Am using Sql server 2008 DB and mobilink sync.

Edit:
Operations i do in sequence:

1.A iPhone loaded with application which uses mobilink for SYNC data.

2.SYNC means UPLOAD(from device to Remote DB)followed by DOWNLOAD(from Remote DB to device).

3.Remote DB means Consolidated DB ; device Db is Ultralite DB.

4.Remote DB has some triggers to fire when certain tables are updated.

5.An UPLOAD from device to Remote will fire triggers when sync upload finished.

6.Very next moment the UPLOAD finished DOWNLOAD to device starts.

7.Exactly same moment those DB triggers will fire.

8.Now a deadlock between DB SYNC(-DOWNLOAD) and trigger(Update queries included within) operations occur.

9.Sync fails with error saying cannot access some tables.

Comment: This sounds like a difficult thing to do. What happens to changes made to the main db when the mobile database is not on-line?

Comment: @simon at rcl The problem is with 'sync-time' only.The sync does upload to main DB first (trigger fired now) then download changes to mobile DB(sync fails because some tables locked by UPDATE queries inside trigger).If there is NO-SYNC there's no problem at all..But i need a solution with online+sync

Comment: Wrap everything remote DB needs to do in a transaction and lock all resources needed. So mobile can only read main DB. When main DB operation is complete decide how to handle out of sync situation. You may set flag or check for lock from client and if changes are running on main DB client does not issue `UPDATE\DELETE` requests with a message to the user.

Comment: @Stoleg i think we can handle this situation when only one client does sync with DB; but my application deals with many clients where "time to sync" and "sync time" is unknown! Using lock/flags would be full of mess in this case.

Comment: It depends on what's going on at DB and at client and what the priorities are and what are the consequences of getting out of sync. We need more information about the operations you do.

Comment: @Stoleg Please check latest edits..

Comment: Are there many triggers? As far as I understand, it not necessrary that download gets updated data? Or even does not use columns updated from uploaded info? If it is true, then you have a deadlock problem, which you need to address, not problem with sync.

Comment: Suggestion: if you interface between mobile and main DB supports it, use parametrised stored procedures: it will be faster by reuse of execution plan. It will be helpful for downloads to.

Comment: @Stoleg There is one trigger but "Many Users with different sync time and time to sync".So multiple use-cases for one issue.

Comment: Is it a big, complex trigger? Can you please answer other questions too. `Update` operation will not finish until trigger for is complete. In case of havy usage you'll end up with many relatively long running operations. Moving multiple statement trigger to separate script or SP will create less blocking.

Comment: @Stoleg simple trigger to update around 30 tables.Even moving it to SP will make lesser blocking by avoiding Trigger-Lock but the UPDATE-QUERIES within SP will have table locks.May be its a small "Time interval" but on live-production its a big issue with multiple users accessing for SYNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lots of work around and Google! Came out with a simple(?!) solution for the problem.
(though the exact problem cannot be solved at this point ..i tried my best).

1. **Keep track of all clients who does a sync**(kind of user details).
2. **Create a sql job scheduler** which contains all the operations to be performed when user syncs.
3. **Announce a "maintenance period"** everyday to **execute the tasks** of sql job with respect to saved user/client sync details.
4. Here keeping track of client details every time is costlier but much needed!
5. Remote consolidated DB "completely-updated" only after maintenance period.

**Any approaches better than this would be appreciated! all Suggestions are welcome!**

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your system is following:

1. Mobile application sends `UPDATE` statement to SQL Server DB.
2. There is `ON UPDATE` trigger, that updates around 30 tables (= at least 30 `UPDATE` statements in the trigger + 1 main update statement)
3. `UPDATE`is executed in single transaction. This transaction ends when Trigger completes all updates.
4. Mobile application does not wait for `UPDATE` to finish and sends multiple `SELECT` statements to get data from database.
5. These `SELECT`statements query same tables as the Trigger above is updating.
6. Blocking and deadlocks occur at some query for some user as Trigger is not completing updates before selects and keeps lock on tables.

When optimizing we are trying make it our processes less easy for computer, achieve same result in less iterations and use less resources or those resources that are more available/less overloaded.

My suggestions for your design:

1. Use parametrized SPs. Every time SQL Server receives any statement it creates Execution plan. For 1 UPDATE statement with a trigger DB needs at least 31 execution plan. It happens on busy Production environment for every connection every time app updates DB. It is a big waste.
2. How SPs would help reduce blocking?
   Now you have 1 transaction for 31 queries, where locks are issued against all tables involved and held until transaction commits. With SP you'll have 31 small transaction and only 1-2 tables will be locked at a time.

Another question I would like to address: **how to do asynchronous updates to your database?**
There is a feature in SQL Server called Service Broker. It allows to process message queue (rows from the queue table) automatically: it monitors queue, takes messages from it and does processing you specify and deletes processes messages from the queue.

For example, you save parameters for your SPs - messages - and Service Broker executes SP with parameters.